# How to bind a specific IPv6 address to a specific user?

Tags: debian, vps, ipv6

I'm running a VPS on Debian 9 that has multiple users and /64 Network of IPv6 addresses. I added a few of them by typing

```
ip -6 addr add *IPv6* dev eth0
```

How do I bind a specific IPv6 address to a specific user so if I run multiple instances of a program in individual users they all communicate only via the appropriate IPv6 address?

**Update:** solution for outgoing connections

```
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m owner --uid-owner *UserName* -j SNAT --to-source *IPv6*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `SNAT` with `iptables`. `iptables` has options to match the user running the process that generates the connection.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Thank you, I've got `ip6tables` working with outgoing connections!